# Postgres database includes a table but I can not see any table when I connect via command line in Docker container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to keep postgresql in a separate service. This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install poetry
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /app/
RUN poetry install
COPY . /app/
RUN python manage.py makemigrations kapp && \
    python manage.py migrate
CMD ["poetry", "run", "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
db:
  container_name: postgresql_db
  image: postgres
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 54321:5432
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=kuser
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kpass
    - POSTGRES_DB=kdb
  networks:
    - backend

app:
  container_name: kapp
  build: .
  ports:
    - 8000:8000
  depends_on:
    - db
  restart: always
volumes:
  - .:/kapp
```

My `models.py`:

```
class Ktable(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    app_label = "kapp"

  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  number = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
```

How I insert data:

```
Ktable.objects.update_or_create(
    number=number,
)
```

and how I fetch data from Ktable:

```
res = Ktable.objects.all()
```

The kapp works fine and res contains what I expected. However, when I connect to the kdb database in the Docker container (via Docker desktop), I do not see any table in the public schema.

```
# psql -U kuser -d kdb 
kdb=# \dt
Do not find any relations.
```

Comment: could you confirm that you don't have another Postgres instance available at localhost's 5432 port.. from what I understand compose file, it would bind container's 5432 port to localhost:54321....

so if there is another DB running bind at 5432, and somehow your app picking DB connection string with default port.. it would connect to other DB

Comment: Good point. Yes, I actually have a postgres running on host. But my attempt to connect to the local machine with kuser will be failed since of not existence role. when I connect with postgres user I do not see the kdb database by running # dt